# Mysql Multi Database Insertion ( Java , Hibernate , Jboss )

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jboss

I have two Mysql Databases(DB1,DB2).I need a solution to the following.

If i try to insert some data into DB1 and if it's down , 
i need the same to be inserted into DB2.
But while inserting into DB2 , 
if the DB1 became up then i need to cancel current insertion ( into DB2 ) and
inert it into the DB1 itself.

Solution's based on java,Hibernate and J boss Data source are feasible.

Comment: are you trying to reinvent the DB Cluster that supports High Availability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds interesting. Is DB2 supposed to be a mirror of DB1? From you description, it sounds like DB2 is supposed to only store data that cannot make it into DB1. Maybe you can have a separate process to reconcile DB1 and DB2, that is, a job that regularly loads data from DB2 into DB1.

Pretty much all databases have all kinds of fault tolerance features already built in. Check out MySQL's  [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-solutions-switch.html). There's no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Yeah the context is same , but in my case if DB1 is down and while inserting into DB2 , DB1 becomes up , so will it insert into DB1 at that time ?

Comment: As u said may be it supports in Mysql replication , but i need to implement this feature in java code or jboss datasource